# How to checkout a Bitbucket Git-LFS repo in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server, git-lfs

I have a Git LFS setup on our Bitbucket server, and can clone it on my Mac since I'm the owner.

Now I'm trying to set this up so a Jenkins job can clone the repo, and so on the SCM section I have

```
Repository URL: git@server.company.com:user/path/repo.git
Credentials: uernamePwCreds
```

It can get to the repo fine, but when it tries to checkout a Git-LFS file, it gets the following access error. See the **Permission denied (publickey)** error on last line.

```
FATAL: Could not checkout 104e35fb26dc1d3ed1689523cccb6e97829c0feb
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 104e35fb26dc1d3ed1689523cccb6e97829c0feb" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Downloading MarcomLite/lib/jets3t-0.6.1/cockpit-0.6.1.jar (144 KB)
Error downloading object: MarcomLite/lib/jets3t-0.6.1/cockpit-0.6.1.jar (716be41): Smudge error: Error downloading MarcomLite/lib/jets3t-0.6.1/cockpit-0.6.1.jar (716be4107b362e413dc1ae29dc88e9b79e680def2c725ecc2d73268c4ea66e75): batch request: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
```

How do I setup the "Git-LFS-specific" level authentication?

I don't want to use a Jenkinsfile for now.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding "Additional Behaviours" -> "Git LFS pull after checkout" in the Git section of the SCM configuration for your job.